# How to get the duration of any stream of a mp4 container with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm not sure, but the following command seems to do just that. Here I get the duration of the first audio stream of the mp4 file:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -i input.mp4
```

However, I'm looking for the equivalent with ffmpeg (if it exists). Your answer is equally valid if it's that it's not possible to do that with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: What's wrong with using `ffprobe`? This type of task is what it is for. The console output of `ffmpeg` isn't meant to be machine parsed.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `ffprobe`, I just need to use `ffmpeg`. I updated the question title to make it more explicit that I don't only want to "get the duration of any stream of a mp4" container, but that I want to do it with ffmpeg.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I still don't quite understand why you are unable or don't want to use `ffprobe`, so my answer would be "use `ffprobe`".

Comment: Why I can't use `ffprobe` is irrelevant...I don't care if it's more complicated (or even impossible) with `ffmpeg`, it's just a constraint I have. I'll take your answer as "Impossible with ffmpeg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v:3 -f null - 2>&1 | tail -3 | grep -oP "(?<=time=).+?\s"`

`0:v:3` will select the fourth video stream. If it exists, output will be a duration e.g. `00:02:57.64`

If it doesn't exist, output will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

.Using `FFmpeg` to get the media file duration, you can do this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -map 0:0 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

For further reading about the [Map option.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)

[Source](https://webkul.com/blog/get-duration-length-of-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg/).

Comment: Where do you specify the type of stream and the index of the stream?

Comment: @maximedupre @llogan for stream selection you can use the option `-map`. I updated the command above using this latter.

Comment: It does return a duration, however I'm note sure it returns the duration of the specific stream. I think it simply returns the duration of the total mp4 container (duration of all streams together)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest it to you if I didn't test it myself. And as you said it seems that the stream selection is not working. I'll check it again and come back to you.